# How do I build a HTML table from Glazed List?

Tags: java, collections, html-table, glazedlists

Lat week I downloaded the Glazed List library into eclipse. I have been looking through the tutorials and it seems that everything is designed to run jTable or SWT. I am need a backing list(Map, table, whatever) for simple HTML tables that can be sortable. I have been doing this by rolling my own classes to create HTML tables from either Lists or Maps(Very Large Lists and Maps). No scripting allowed.

Is Glazed List overkill for what I am wanting to do? If there is a way, could someone point me in the right direction, perhaps a example or a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not exactly the right tool for the job.  GlazedLists was created to support mostly Swing or SWT based UIs.  You can get it to work well as a backing model for the HTML table on the server side, but you would have to create the rendering code yourself.

In this URL you can see that the documentation mentions that it can be used with swing or SWT out of the box, but no HTML mentioned:

http://sites.google.com/site/glazedlists/propaganda/features#TOC-Swing-or-SWT

All said, however, it does make a good backing model.  Creating the rendering code might not be so hard.

Answer (score 1):

We had a volunteer for an [official GWT port](http://www.nabble.com/GlazedList-GWT-td23002550.html), but it's not available yet. In an unrelated effort, there's an EventList in the [gwt-stuff project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-stuff/wiki/GwtStuffEventList), but I haven't investigated it.